# how to get second column value from first column value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: mysql image]

I want to print meta_value with the use of meta_key column. Like I want to print only phone number with the help of billing_phone in php mysql.

Comment: To select the meta_value specifically you can do `SELECT meta_value FROM` ... But that seems too simple for you to need to ask that. I think there's more to this than you have explained but there isn't really enough context to understand precisely what your issue is. If you want to find only rows where the meta_key contains "phone" then you've already achieved that with the query you showed.

Comment: I want to print phone number where found 'billing_phone' in meta_key column

Comment: Well the query you showed already gets that information from the table...so what exactly is the problem you're having? If you want the query to be more precise you could write `SELECT meta_value FROM rks_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'billing_phone'`, but in the example you showed above the result would essentially be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a prepared statement as follows:

```sql
SET @metaKey='billing_phone'; 
SET @tableName='rks_usermeta';

SET @alterStmtStr=CONCAT('SELECT *, ', @metaKey, ' FROM ', @tableName);             

PREPARE stmtName FROM @alterStmtStr;
EXECUTE stmtName; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtName;
```

Comment: Why is a prepared statement specifically the solution here? You didn't explain why the OP "needs" this or what problem it's solving.

Comment: Question was about outputting the value of a particular column that is 

SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] from my_table;

I think prepared statement is the only way you can achieve that.

Comment: They already know which column they want to select